# How can I reference the following html elements using java and selenium?

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium, automation

I want to access the following elements with the only indicator of value using java.
All the text values identified with option value, under name="txnSource", are selections that can be made from a drop-down selector.

I'd like to automate the selection of the value from the drop-down box is why I need to know how to access the values... 
There is no "findElement(By.value("value"))" so how can I access the element by value ??

I think accessing by xpath would be extremely volatile. Also, any change in the options in the drop-down would require a whole reworking of the xpath identification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an option from pick list like this

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("txnSource"))).selectByVisibleText("Text- Stock Movement (DOGS)");
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you can do any of those:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value='500']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='500']")).click();
```

or use [`Select` and `selectByValue()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#selectByValue%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("txnSource")));
select.selectByValue("500");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java I think it would be something this way

```
IWebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.Name("txnSource"));
SelectElement clickThis = new SelectElement(dropDownListBox);
clickThis.SelectByValue("500");
```

This is how it is done in Ruby

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:name, "txnSource")).select_by(:value, "500")
```